# Where is the System.Net.Http.WebRequestHandler source code?

Tags: c#, .net

To much fanfare it was announced that there was now a Roslyn powered index for the [.NET Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) and that

```
The version of the framework that we currently have indexed is .NET framework 
version 4.5.1.
```

Yet when I go there to look at [HttpClient](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Net.Http/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs) code all I get are stubs and I cannot find any code for the bits that make it run like [System.Net.Http.WebRequestHandler](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=WebRequestHandler).

Where can I find this code and why hasn't it been included already?

Comment: If you cannot find it over as Microsoft, maybe looking at the Mono source can help you? https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Net.Http.WebRequest/System.Net.Http.WebRequest/WebRequestHandler.cs

Comment: Nice link. Thanks. Still like to know where it 'actually' is. Not on https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/ either.

Comment: Now there aren't even stubs in reference source. System.Net.Http is gone completely!

Answer (score 43):

I found the solution on [blogs.msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/08/07/httpclient-httpclienthandler-and-httpwebrequesthandler.aspx):

"The WebRequestHandler is not included in the System.Net.Http DLL but rather in System.Net.Http.WebRequest DLL so you have to explicitly include that as a reference in order to see it."

Comment: So Roslyn will find it, but what about google ? where is it located on the internet web site ?

Answer (score 0):

add assembly System.Net.Http.WebRequest

Comment: This answer does not add anything to the previous one. You could just +1 the other answer or add a comment.